# address out of bounds about buffer overflow

Tags: c, function-pointers, buffer-overflow

Recently, I was trying to use point clobbering to utilize the vulnerability of my XP VM.  The thing is that, I has changed address the function pointed to to another function address(in this case function arc injection(R)), but when the program jump to the function "arc injection(R)", the GDB tells me that R is address 0xbalbala out of bounds? I some kind of known that this may relate to scope of the variable. Can any one tell me how can I use point clobbering to jump to a function and use its argument? Thank you so much.

```
void ArcInjection(char *R)
{
   printf("In ArcInjection()\n");
   system(R);
}

void (*FuncPtr)(int,int, char **);
```

here is a part of switch:

```
case 5:
  ArcInjection(Command);
  break;
case 6:
  FuncPtr(argv[++i][0]-48,argc,argv);  // I changed the address this function pointed to to the address of case 5, but in this case case 5 cannot use its argument Command, which has been defined in the main program.
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see how you assign `FuncPtr`. Off the top of my head, I can see a couple problems. First, the address of `case 5` does not point to a function, so there's no argument or return handling code. Second, the argument list to `ArcInjection` is not compatible with the argument list for `FuncPtr`, so they will be interpreted completely differently.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I failed to pass argument to `case 5 `. The scope is limited to `case 6`; i probably should try another way to use  `case 6`, since`Command` is not in `FuncPtr`'s argument list and my professor does not suggest me to change the code. Thank you.

Comment: Like...it doesn't compile? Or?    `argv` and `argc` aren't globally scoped, so nobody except `main()` can see them.  If you assign them to a globally declared and visible variable, then I don't see why your function pointer can't use the values.

Comment: Yeah! I found that the method to enter other function jumping from another function, you have  to find the address in the assembly language rather than using the address of C code. THAT'S REALLY IMPORTANT for utilizing the vulnerability of buffer overflow.